# Memory Set in 32-bit architecture

Tags: c, memory

I want develop the code of memset for PowerPc architecture.

I want know, why in 32-bit architecture is better to set 32-bits by 32-bits instead of byte by byte?

Comment: I don't know anything about the PPC architecture specifically but in general, if an architecture has 32-bit registers and instructions that allow you to push register contents to memory, then it's easy to see that you have the option to zero out 32 bits of memory instead of 8 with the same number of "actions" (if not fewer).

Comment: It generally results in fewer instructions executed per byte of input.

Comment: Depending on the processor, it's probably fewer cache / memory operations, writing one 32 bit value instead of writing four 8 bit values.

Comment: If I asked you to carry a bag of sand across the room, would you carry it one grain at a time?